# Is my proof that $\ker(T)\subseteq \{v-T(v) \mid v \in V\}$ correct

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Given the following: "Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=T$

**To show:**

$\ker(T) \subseteq \{v-T(v)\mid v\in V\}$

**My proof:**

Let $v\in V $.

Suppose $v\in \ker(T)$ 
$\iff T(v)=\underline{0}$
$\iff T(v)=T(T(v))=\underline{0}$
$\iff T(v)-T(T(v))=\underline{0}$
$\iff T(v-T(v))=\underline{0}$
$\iff v-(T(v))\in \ker(T)$

hence $v\in \ker(T)$$\iff v-(T(v))\in \ker(T)$

and if $v$ being in $\ker(T)$ is equivalent to $v-T(v)$ being in $\ker(T)$ then $v$ must be equal to $v-T(V)$ (is this deduction here correct? The logic used is that if person A is in the park is equivalent to person B being in the park then person A **must be** person B)

Hence $v\in\{v-T(v)\mid v\in V\} $

Hence $\ker(T) \subseteq \{v-T(v)\mid v\in V\}$ as required.

Comment: If $v \in \ker (T)$, then you directly have $v - T(v) = v - 0 = v$ anyway, so $v - T(v) = v \in \ker(T)$, even without the assumption $T^2 = T$. And the paragraph with "the logic used is..." does not make sense to me.

Comment: Logical equivalence is not identity: a real number $x$ is in the interval $[-1,1]$ if and only if $-x$ is in the interval. That doesn't mean that $1 = -1$! The equivalence is between *conditions*, not an identity of objects.

Comment: You are proving nothing at all, I'm afraid. The statement $v\in\ker(T)\iff v-T(v)\in\ker(T)$ is not true, by the way. Under the assumptions in the question, $v-T(v)\in\ker(T)$ *for every* $v\in V$, because $T(v-T(v))=T(v)-T^2(v)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $w \in \ker(T)$. In order to show that $w \in \{v-T(v) \mid v \in V\}$ as well, you need to *produce* a choice of $v \in V$ such that $w = v - T(v)$. There is a very simple choice of $v$ that will make this work.

Comment: Is the choice simply to let v=w?

Comment: I see, so the statement that we're proving is in fact "$\forall w \in ker(T), \exists v \in V$  such that $w=v-T(v)$"??